# Amazon Route 53 domain - Server IP address could not be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I am trying to access a domain I registered on AWS and my browser says:

> Site Can't Be reached. 21fighterpilots.com's server IP address could not be found.

I followed this [Getting Started with Amazon Route 53 - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/getting-started.html#getting-started-find-domain-name) directly and still does not work. Checked many other troubleshooting forums and guides, nothing has worked.

[image: Route 53 View]

This is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcSQ9.jpg)

Comment: It works for me (points to S3 and gives an error, but the DNS part works). Either you just had to wait longer for the DNS entry to propagate, or something's a bit funny with DNS resolution on your end. Did you want that DNS name to point to an S3 bucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have properly configured your traffic policy . 

You have created Record Set for **"www.21fighterpilots.com"**,but you also need to create another Record Set for **"21fighterpilots.com"** with requried value. This should resolve your issue and should be able to browse **"21fighterpilots.com"**.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you've only created a record for "www.21fighterpilots.com" but you're trying to access "21fighterpilots.com". They are different addresses. Create a second record without anything in the name field in Route 53 and you should get the results you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks so much! I figured it out. I am very new to AWS so this helps a lot. I created the new record set for 21fighterpilots.com and it is now working.